# Find the minimum value of $x^2+y^2$, where $x,y$ are nonnegative integers and $x+y=k$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Question: Let $k$ be a fixed odd positive integer. Find the minimum value of $x^2+y^2$, where $x,y$ are nonnegative integers and $x+y=k$.

My approach: After trying some examples I can conjecture that, the minimum value of $x^2+y^2$ is attained at $$x=\left\lceil \frac{k}{2}\right\rceil \text{and } y=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor \text{and equivalently at } x=\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor \text{and }y=\left\lceil \frac{k}{2}\right\rceil.$$ This also implies that the minimum value of $x^2+y^2=\left\lceil \frac{k}{2}\right\rceil^2+\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor^2.$

But, how to prove the same?

Also, since $x+y=k$, this implies that $(x+y)^2=k^2\implies x^2+y^2=k^2-2xy.$ Therefore, we need to maximize $xy$ in order to minimize $x^2+y^2$.

But, again this is leading me nowhere.

Comment: If Lagrange multiplier can be used, $x=y=k/2,\,x^2+y^2=k^2/2 \,$ as you guessed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{2}+y^{2}&=\frac{(x+y)^{2}+(x-y)^{2}}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $(x+y)$ is fixed, we minimize $x^{2}+y^{2}$ by minimizing $|x-y|$

Answer (score 1):

Why not to write 
$$y=k-x \implies x^2+y^2=2x^2-2kx+k^2=2 \left(x-\frac{k}{2}\right)^2+\frac{k^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

AM-GM: $x+y=k \geqslant 2 \sqrt{xy}$

${xy} \leqslant \frac {k^2} {4} $

$x^2+y^2=k^2-2xy\geqslant \frac {k^2} {2}$

If $k$ is even, then $minimum\; x^2+y^2=\frac {k^2} {2}$

If $k$ is odd, then 
$minimum\; x^2+y^2=\frac {k^2+1} {2}$